# If I run multiple 32bits applications in a 64bits, will each one run at full speed?

Tags: architecture, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture

I'm running a really old 32-bit application that extracts data, since I'm using a 64-bit processor it is really limited in time.

My solution was to open 5 at a time and extract from different banks of data and after merge it with SQL.

My question is: if I do that, am I really going faster or is it just 5 applications running in 20% of its speed? I don't know how the computer would deal with that. I have to admit that I'm not very into modern computer architecture.

Ps: If I'm mistaken, do you think there is a way to optimize this speed in any other way? Ps2: When I check the CPU usage is getting closer to 100% and the memory usage is around 7GB out of 16GB, that is around 40%, that's why I stopped at 5 parallel running applications

Comment: Do you have a multi-core CPU with at least 5 cores, so each process can run on a CPU core?  32 vs. 64-bit is irrelevant; a single-threaded 32-bit process occupies a core exactly the same way that a 64-bit single-threaded process would.

Comment: Yep it is a multi-core my question is pretty much if they are all using the same core or they are sharing it, thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

On **Linux** it is possible to pin each run of an application on different core of a multi-core system. E.g.,

```
taskset -c 0 application &
taskset -c 1 application
```

Otherwise the OS decides the best way to schedule multiple jobs.